# PHP make statements in TEXT FILE

Tags: php

I have ips.txt file, there is :
31.146.153.182

ENDFILE-> this was my ip

and I have index.php

```
<?php 
    $file ='ips.txt';
    $ips = file($file);
    $client =  $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    if ($ips[0]==$client)  { 
        echo  "ip is blocked";
    } else {
       echo "it does not work";
    }
?>
```

And this script does not equaling `$ips[0] == $client`,  but in `echo` it's actually the same.

Comment: And the question is...

Comment: Maybe you wanted your code to read the ips.txt?

Comment: I want to hide the client inline extesnion  defend on IP's , I record some Ip and move into ips.txt with new lines,  then I want to hide innline extension with client's if IP is exists

Comment: check for spaces at the end of the line or begining. and apply a `trim` to `$ips[0]` if you have spaces.

Answer (score 0):

By default, `file` copies along newlines, [as documented](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php#refsect1-function.file-returnvalues). But the newline is not in the `REMOTE_ADDR` result.

You can avoid this behavior by adding the `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` flag to the file function, like this:

```
$ips = file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

Or you can alternatively trim the lines in your check:

```
if (trim($ips[0]) == $client) { ... }
```